# Google products stopping after changing tab with STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, youtube

While in YouTube listening to this music,

[image]

when I changed tab then could see the icon of Youtube change to

[image]

and going to it can see the following

[image]

> Código de erro: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Then, when going to Gmail

[image]

the same happened after changing tab

[image]

Comment: Did you restart Chrome?

Comment: @harrymc I'll try that. It happened out of nowhere

Comment: @harrymc restarting Chrome solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem will stay unknown, since restarting Chrome solved the problem.